# Recursively list files in an archive

Tags: php, archive

I'm creating a method that will inspect files in an upload folder and some of these files are archive (**tar, tar.gz, zip, rar, etc**). I would like to read these archive files and list all files in a nested tree format.

For example, I have an archive file called `sandwich.tar.gz`, I would like it to be listed as below:-

```
sandwich.tar.gz
    lettuce
    mayonaise
    cheese
    bread (directory)
        wholemeal
```

My code thus far:-

```
<?php $archive = new PharData('/upload/directory/sandwich.tar.gz');
foreach($archive as $file) {
        echo $file . "<br />";
}
```

But it failed to list files inside the `bread` directory. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 5):

You can do this using a `RecursiveIteratorIterator`, because `PharData` extends the `Phar` class and the `Phar` class extends the `RecursiveDirectoryIterator` class:

```
$archive = new PharData('/upload/directory/sandwich.tar.gz');

foreach (new RecursiveIteratorIterator($archive) as $file) {
    echo $file . "<br />";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Although this question is rather dated, considering the stupidity and the uselessness of the previous answer, I cannot but reply.

It seems whatever PHP does is always non-standard and awkward at best...

You got it right to inspect the first level. However, the objects returned from the iteration are not of the same type, thus calling `foreach` on them will lead to failure.

Iterating on a [`PharData`](http://php.net/manual/class.phardata.php) object gives you [`PharFileInfo`](http://php.net/manual/class.pharfileinfo.php) ones. From there you can check for the file type (checking if it is a directory with the inherited [`isDir()`](http://php.net/manual/splfileinfo.isdir.php) method).

From there, you will need to create another PharData object on the path to the resource obtained from the (also inherited) [`getPathname()`](http://php.net/manual/splfileinfo.getpathname.php) (*sic*, not `getPathName()` say the docs!) method. You will then be able to iterate over it...

Full example:

```
<?php
    $archive = new PharData('/upload/directory/sandwich.tar.gz');
    foreach($archive as $file) {
        echo $file;
        if($file->isDir()) {
            echo ':';
            $dir = new PharData($file->getPathname());
            foreach($dir as $child) {
                echo "<br />$child";
            }
        }
        echo "<br />";
    }
?>
```

Of course, that kills easy recursion if you have multiple levels in your archive. You will have to cook your own recursive crawler...

Answer (score -3):

Some advice that I was given once, and think about often, comes to mind: code will do EXACTLY what you ask it to do: nothing more, nothing less.

Ask the machine: 'if this is a directory, please display the contents?'

Your function thinks that it is looking for a $file, and thus outputs the name of that file.

Consider http://php.net/manual/en/function.readdir.php and http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-dir.php

Comment: The question is about read a tar archive, not a simple directory.